# Delete rows within a given time interval

Tags: mysql, group-by, delete, datetime

I have created a table with the following values:

```
create table MyTable (id int, dtdate datetime, serialNum int, serialCode int, status int);
insert into MyTable values
(1, 2012-12-20 01:01:00, 1, 10, 3),
(2, 2012-12-20 01:01:00, 1, 10, 4),
(3, 2012-12-20 01:05:00, 2, 11, 3),
(4, 2012-12-20 01:08:00, 2, 13, 4),
(5, 2012-12-20 01:13:00, 1, 10, 6),
(6, 2012-12-20 01:38:00, 1, 10, 3),
(7, 2012-12-20 01:39:00, 2, 11, 3),
(8, 2012-12-20 01:44:00, 1, 10, 3),
(9, 2012-12-20 01:52:00, 1, 10, 3),
(10, 2012-12-20 01:58:00, 2, 20, 4);
```

I would like to delete rows from the table that have the same `serialNum` and `serialCode` within an interval of 30 minutes and the same to be repeated again with the rows that falls within the next 30 minutes. So in the end, I would have the following result:

```
(1, 2012-12-20 01:01:00, 1, 10, 3),
(3, 2012-12-20 01:05:00, 2, 11, 3),
(6, 2012-12-20 01:38:00, 1, 10, 3),
(7, 2012-12-20 01:39:00, 2, 11, 3),
(10, 2012-12-20 01:58:00, 2, 20, 4);
```

I have the code below that only deletes the consecutive duplicate rows. I am not sure how I can incorporate datetime with where clause.

```
delete from MyTable_duplicate where nSequence in (
select nSequence from MyTable m1 
where 0 < (
  select count(*) 
  from MyTable m2 
  where m2.id = m1.id - 1 
  and m2.serialNum = m1.serialNum 
  and m2.serialCode = m1.serialCode)
  GROUP BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dtdate) DIV 1800 order by id);
```

Here, `MyTable_duplicate` is a copy of `MyTable`. Any help/idea would be highly appreciated!
 Thanks

Comment: you probably want to use the lag() function, or simulate the lag function if you're not on mysql 8.0, explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303532/simulate-lag-function-in-mysql
then delete rows where the lag-row difference is less than 30 minutes.

Comment: Please sort Your data with `select * from mytable order by serialNum, serialCode, id;` query and then explain record by record like "Record id=N is [not] deleted because ...". And especially explain why You delete record id=2 and keep id=1 - these records are full duplicates by (serialNum, serialCode, dtdate).

Comment: Use a "self-join".